# java mocking custom objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

```
public class MainClass  {

    public void makeCall() {
        CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
        obj.testMethod();
    }
}
```

I want to unit test the `makeCall()`. So i have to mock the `CustomObject` in the above sample. I am using Mockito as the mock framework.But when i mock the object like `mock(CustomObject.class)`. `makeCall()` method always call the actual object not the mocked one.Is there anyway to mock the local objects. Please help

Comment: You have to pass the mock to this code. Not having the client code invoke `new` is the whole point of dependency injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unit-test-friendly version of your `MainClass` should have `CustomObject` injected, for example:

```
public class MainClass  {
    private CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();  // a default one if none is provided

    public void setCustomObject(CustomObject customObject) {
        this.customObject = customObject;
    }

    public void makeCall() {
        this.customObject.testMethod();
    }
}
```

and your test will look like:

```
CustomObject mockCustomObject = mock(CustomObject.class);
when(mockCustomObject.testMethod()).thenReturn(...);

MainClass sut = new MainClass();
sut.setCustomObject(mockCustomObject);

sut.makeCall();

verify(mockCustomObject).testMethod();
```

With Mockito's annotation, it can be further simplified as:

```
public class MyClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MainClass mainClass;

    @Mock
    private CustomObject mockCustomObject;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  // or use mockito runner
    }

    @Test
    public void testMakeCall() {
        when(mockCustomObject.testMethod()).thenReturn(...);
        mainClass.makeCall();
        verify(mockCustomObject).testMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i test a factory method ?

Comment: I can't see how this question is related to the original one. Please raise a proper question to give more information on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. What you can do is to refactor the local object to a field or a parameter like this:

```
public class MainClass  {

    public void makeCall(CustomObject obj) {
        obj.testMethod();
    }
}
```

Your current program violates the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) so it is advised to refactor it anyway.

If you make the field an instance variable you can mock it easily if you have a setter or you initialize it based on a constructor parameter. Example for the latter:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private CustomObject objMock;

    private MyClass objToTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        objToTest = new MyClass(objMock);
    }

}
```

Comment: can i mock the object if i make it an instance variable

Answer (score 0):

Not with Mockito proper, no. You have to modify your code so that you create your custom object from another source and mock that source.

This is what I'd recommend... However there does exist a solution with [PowerMockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/):

```
final CustomObject obj = mock(CustomObject.class);

PowerMockito.whenNew(CustomObject.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(obj);
```

However, uh. Refactor your code. You'll be all the better for it.