# Mocking factory pattern in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, factory-pattern

It may look similar to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539036/java-mocking-custom-objects/28539229?noredirect=1#comment45418054_28539229). I have a simple animal factory.

```
public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal getAnimal(String type) {
        if ("canine".equals(type)) {
            return new Dog();
        } else {
            return new Cat();
        }
    }

}
```

and class for

```
public interface Animal {
    void makeSound();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    void makeSound() {
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    void makeSound() {
    }
}
```

I have some doubts. Does `AnimalFactory` violate the dependency inversion principle? Is it possible to unit test `AnimalFactory` without making calls to the actual `Dog` and `Cat` classes or do I have to refactor my code?

Comment: Please don't use _Junit_ as a verb.

Comment: Are you using any Dependency injection framework in your code? I.e Google Guice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not violating the dependency inversion principle if there are no dependencies to inject.

In any case the `Factory` is a *creational* design pattern and you should test that it does indeed create (instantiate) the right things.

Yes, you should test that it does return objects where `instanceof Dog` and `instanceof Cat` are true.

If you must test your factory without actually calling the constructors of `Dog` and `Cat` (due to the initialization that they do), I suggest refactoring the factory class like this:

```
public class AnimalFactory {
    public Animal createAnimal(String type) {
        if ("canine".equals(type)) {
            return createDog();
        } else {
            return createCat();
        }
    }

    Dog createDog() { return new Dog(); }

    Cat createCat() { return new Cat(); }
}
```

And the test would look like this:

```
public class AnimalFactoryTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateDog() throws Exception {
        AnimalFactory mockFactory = mock(AnimalFactory.class);
        when(mockFactory.createAnimal(anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();

        mockFactory.createAnimal("canine");
        verify(mockFactory).createDog();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateCat() throws Exception {
        AnimalFactory mockFactory = mock(AnimalFactory.class);
        when(mockFactory.createAnimal(anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();

        mockFactory.createAnimal("cat");
        verify(mockFactory).createCat();
    }
}
```

Incidentally, the naming convention for `Factory` pattern methods are `createXyz` rather than `getXyz`.

Good luck.

Comment: But when i test it will make a call to the actual class

Comment: Yes it will make a call to the Dog and Cat class constructors. Is that ok, or is that a problem (class ties up resources in the constructor, for example) ?

Comment: Can i mock that classes ?

Comment: @Nikhil Why do you want to mock the classes?

Comment: @Duncan i want to prevent the actual calls because it do some initialization. i want my test not run that

Comment: So you got bad design there - inside Dog and Cat classes.

Comment: That's true, but maybe someone else was the author of `Dog` and `Cat`, and we don't have the option to change them...